# Activate anaconda environment during vagrant shell provisioning

Tags: shell, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision, miniconda

I am using vagrant (1.9.1 on MacOSX Sierra) to provision `ubuntu/xenial64` box on VirtualBox to run a python app. I am unable to activate a conda environment using the normal shell command `source` while provisioning. In my `bootstrap.sh`, I have the following lines for creation of a new environment and then switching to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e # Exit script immediately on first error.
set -x # Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/conda create --name envmycondaenvironment python=3.5 # environment with python3.5
source activate envgatherurls
```

I receive the following error from vagrant.

```
==> default: + source activate envmycondaenvironment
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 21: activate: No such file or directory
```

Why is `activate` not found by the shell script? I verified that `/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/` where `activate` can be found has been added to PATH in the `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `activate` is provided by `conda` and is not automatically added to the `PATH` environment variable. Please note that the `bootstrap.sh` script runs as `root` and not the `vagrant` user. So you need to make sure that the `.bashrc` for the `root` user has `/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin` in it's path. If I were you, I had rather do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e # Exit script immediately on first error.
set -x # Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

export PATH=/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
conda create --name envmycondaenvironment python=3.5 # environment with python3.5
source activate envgatherurls
```